# Pesquisa por "2>&1" falha e utiliza "21"

Tags: bug, status-intencional, pesquisa

Ao realizar uma pesquisa por um pedaço de código que faz parte do título de uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55765/223):

```
2>&1
```

A chave de pesquisa é convertida em:

```
21
```

E apresenta [resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=2%3E%261) que contém `21` ao invés de resultados que contém `2>&1`.

[image: Captura de tela]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solução: **[procure com aspas, `"2>&1"`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%222%3E%261%22)**.

Comment: Curioso que com aspas simples (plicas) `'2>&1'` [não funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%272%3E%261%27) ...

Comment: @Sergio Com plica só complica ;)

Comment: É solução ou gambiarra?

Comment: Do ponto de vista do usuário, resolve o problema, @JorgeB. Se é solução ou gambiarra depende do que os devs do site acharem. Se botarem um `status-bydesign` na pergunta, é solução. Senão, gambiarra :)